# Solving ODE in Scilab

Tags: ode, scilab

I am trying to do some electric circuit analysis in `Scilab` by solving an `ODE`. But I need to change an `ODE` depending on current value of the function. I have implemented the solution in `Scala` using `RK4` method and it works perfectly. Now I am trying to do the same but using standard functions in `Scilab`. And it is not working. I have tried to solve these two ODEs seperately and it is OK.

```
clear
state = 0 // state 0 is charging, 1 is discharging
vb = 300.0; vt = 500.0; 
r = 100.0; rd = 10.0;
vcc = 600;
c = 48.0e-6;

function dudx = curfunc(t, uu)
    if uu < vb then state = 0
    elseif uu > vt state = 1
    end

    select state
    case 0 then // charging
        dudx = (vcc - uu) / (r * c)
    case 1 then // discharging
        dudx = - uu / (rd * c) + (vcc - uu) / (r * c)
    end
endfunction
y0 = 0
t0 = 0
t = 0:1e-6:10e-3

%ODEOPTIONS=[1, 0, 0, 1e-6, 1e-12, 2, 500, 12, 5, 0, -1, -1]
y = ode(y0, t0, t, 1e-3, 1e-6, curfunc)
clear %ODEOPTIONS
plot(t, y)
```

so here I am solving for a node voltage, if node voltage is exceeding top threshold (vt) then discharging `ODE` is used, if node voltage is going below the bottom voltage (vb) then charging `ODE` is used. I have tried to play with `%ODEOPTIONS` but no luck

Comment: Could you please document the problem cases, the script as it is runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think it boils down to a standard problem: The standard ODE solvers have step size control. In contrast to the fixed step size of RK4. For step size control to work, the ODE function needs to have differentiability at least of the same order as the order of the method. Jumps as in your function are thus extremely unfortunate.

Another point to consider is that the internal steps of the method are not always in increasing time, they may jump backwards. See the coefficient table for Dormand-Prince for an example. Thus event based model changes as in your problem may lead to strange effects if the first problem were circumvented.

---

### Workaround (not really a solution)

Declare `state` as a global variable, since as a local variable the value gets always reset to the global constant 0.

```
function dudx = curfunc(t, uu)
    global state
    ...
endfunction
...
y = ode("fix",y0, t0, t, rtol, atol, curfunc)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the ode("root"...) option.

The code will ressemble to
    clear
    state = 0 // state 0 is charging, 1 is discharging
    vb = 300.0; vt = 500.0; 
    r = 100.0; rd = 10.0;
    vcc = 600;
    c = 48.0e-6;

```
function dudx = charging(t, uu)
//uu<vt
  dudx = (vcc - uu) / (r * c)
endfunction
function e=chargingssurf(t,uu)
  e=uu-vt
endfunction

function dudx = discharging(t, uu)
//uu<vb
  dudx = - uu / (rd * c) + (vcc - uu) / (r * c)
endfunction
function e=dischargingssurf(t,uu)
  e=uu-vb
endfunction

y0 = 0
t0 = 0
t = 0:1e-6:10e-3

Y=[];
T=[];
[y,rt] = ode("root",y0, t0, t, 1e-3, 1e-6, charging,1,chargingssurf);
disp(rt)
k=find(t(1:$-1)<rt(1)&t(2:$)>=rt(1))
Y=[Y y];;
T=[T t(1:k) rt(1)];
[y,rt] = ode("root",y($), rd(1), t(k+1:$), 1e-3, 1e-6, discharging,1,dischargingssurf);
Y=[Y y];
T=[T t(k+1:$)];

plot(T, Y)
```

The discharging code seems to be wrong...